# What can be derived from the metric tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, computational-physics, curvature

I am working on a  computational project about General Relativity. In this process, I want to code 'the stuff' that can be derivable from the metric tensor. So far, I have coded Riemann Tensor, Weyl Tensor, Einstein Tensors, Ricci Tensor, Ricci scalar. What are the other essential/needed quantities in the GR calculations that can be coded?

Some notes to answer the comments:

1. It's not precisely numerical. I will not solve the Einstein field equations for a given energy stress-energy tensor etc.
2. The program's purpose is to obtain possible mathematical objects that belong to GR (tensors, etc.) If the user only knows metric tensor and nothing else.
3. I am using / will use python to calculate these things.  It's also kind of a relativistic tool, yes.

Comment: If it is numerical you need the numerical relativity book, as it is not as straightforward as applying a scheme to a PDE.

Comment: What exactly is the application that you're coding for?  I think this question is very difficult to answer, because there's a big question mark of "what is the purpose of this program?"  Numerically solving GR in an initaial boundary problem is very different from finding the geodesics of a particular spacetime, which is ALSO different from trying to do something like semiclassical gravity on a fixed background, and that is different from trying to create a computer image of what a black hole would look like.

Comment: Or is this just a "general purpose tool for relativists to use," and it's more an excirsise for you to repllicate the functions of one of the Maple or Mathematica packagess discussed below?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I answered some of your questions in the op.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you know you have a hard job ahead of you. Wishing you success. In order to know the things that physicists need in this area, I would recommend you first see these two packages: [xAct](http://www.xact.es/) (in Wolfram Mathematica) and [GRtensor](http://grtensor.phy.queensu.ca/) (in Maple). These are really great. Here I summarize some of the most important things (with appropriate links) that come to my mind:

1. Many essential operations in GR including [Covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#:%7E:text=The%20derivative%20along%20a%20curve,called%20absolute%20or%20intrinsic%20derivative.), [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative), etc (you can find these in any GR textbook's index part)
2. [Einstein's field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) in flat, de Sitter and anti-de Sitter backgrounds
3. [Geodesic deviation equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation) and related topics
4. [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#:%7E:text=In%201974%2C%20British%20physicist%20Stephen,distance%20of%20the%20event%20horizon.) (related to the [surface gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gravity))
5. A code for computing [Unruh temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect#:%7E:text=The%20Unruh%20temperature%20has%20the,called%20the%20Hawking%E2%80%93Unruh%20temperature.) for accelerating Observer.
6. [Frame dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging)
7. [Bekenstein-Hawking entropy formula](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bekenstein-Hawking_entropy)
8. [Wald entropy](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9307038) (for higher derivative gravity models)
9. A code for testing [Killing vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field)
10. Perhaps some codes for computing [Komar mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komar_mass) or [ADM mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism).
11. [Kretschmann scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann_scalar)
12. [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols)

...

And, a number of important metrics/coordinates in GR and Cosmology such as

13. [Schwarzschild spacetime metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric)
14. [Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates#:%7E:text=In%20general%20relativity%20Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres,geometry%20for%20a%20black%20hole.&text=The%20surface%20of%20the%20star,in%20the%20Kruskal%2DSzekeres%20coordinates.)
15. [Eddington–Finkelstein coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington%E2%80%93Finkelstein_coordinates)
16. [Kerr spacetime metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric)
17. [Boyer-Lindquist coordinates (for Kerr spacetime)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20description%20of,of%20a%20Kerr%20black%20hole.)
18. [Kerr-Newman spacetime metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric)
19. [Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric)

.
.
.

For this purpose, I think the ["Catalogue of Spacetimes"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184) by  Mueller & Grave can help you a lot about this. In this book we read:

> The aim of the catalogue is to give a quick reference for students
> who need some basic facts of the most well-known spacetimes in GR.

In addition, I highly recommend you to search in [this site](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage) (nLab).

**Finally, according to your edit, I have three suggestions:**

i) It would be nice if you could define the most commonly used metrics by default in your program (see items 13-19, please).

ii) It would be nice if you consider the possibility of defining metrics in dimensions higher or lower than 4 dimensions (they are very important from different aspects). This feature will increase the usefulness and also the number of users of your program. Some examples of lower/higher dimensional black hole spacetimes are

20. [BTZ black hole metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTZ_black_hole) (in 3 dimensions)
21. [Charged rotating BTZ black hole metric](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9912259) (in 3 dimensions)
22. [Higher dimensional Kerr black hole](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0507080)

...

iii) It would be nice if you provide a graphical environment (if possible) for your program, in which users can obtain a desired property for their metric by a click. In fact, sometimes it is not easy for undergraduate or even some of graduate students to work with those packages (GRtensor/xAct) and such a program will be useful. For example, see this [handy calculator for Hawking radiation](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator) of static black holes, which is useful and easy to work (by Viktor Toth, a member here).

***Good luck***

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Its a personal-project and I ll try to do my best as I can to do some stuff. I ll definitly try to implement your suggestions, as best I can.  For more information about the purpose of the program you can look the op.

Comment: Dear @Free, according to your edit, I added three suggestions. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I dont know why they closed the question

Comment: @Free - In addition, you can ask new questions about more details.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll consider that according to the progress

Comment: @Free - I hope to see your program in future (It can be useful for me). Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So far, I have done 11-12 and ii) I am also thinking to add i) and iii) which I think would be great. The only problem is that python sometimes cannot simplify (or I could not find how to do it.) complex mathematical expressions. So that's a bit problematic. I'll also add the essential metrics to the program. Between 1-10, I am not sure I can add them all, but probably I can do some of them.

Comment: I have created the GitHub page. Anyone who would like to use the program can try it... Here is the link https://github.com/seVenVo1d/General-Relativity-Tensor-Calculations

Comment: @Free - Great! Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: I did it :p I think it's really great. You guys can check it out.

Comment: @Free - hey, I took a look at it. Honestly, it looks great! I suggest you put that link (with a little explanation) in your Stack Exchange profile.

Comment: Thanks, I did :)

Comment: @Free - Easy to work with! I recommend further developing the program in future. As far as I know, there is not such an easy tensorial calculator for GR computations. It is very helpful for students.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I tried my best to make it good but as you said it can be further improved I guess. Yes I think the same way as well. I'll try to improve it further in time..Maybe I can make it much better in the future..

Comment: Hey again. I have included the covariant derivative option and changed the GUI a lot. Maybe you want to look at it again. In the future I'll also try to implement Lie derivative and hawking radiation calculator

Comment: @Free - Great! Thanks for informing me. I saw it; it looks nice! In a few months, I will start a computational project on rotating black holes and I intend to test your program together with mathematica/maple tensorial packages. If that project continues without any problems, I will definitely inform you about the result of working with your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That can be very helpful for me. I am personally checking every step, but of course, there could have something that I have missed. If you want to find any problems, you can also create an issue on the Github page.

Answer (score 2):

- Metric $ds^2$ in Cartesian/Spherical/... coordinates
- Inverse of the metric
- Angle between $d^{(1)}x^{\alpha}$ and $d^{(2)}x^{\alpha}$
- Christoffel symbols
- Geodesic equations
- Geodesic equations in Newtonian limit
- Components of generalized momentum
- Riemann tensor
- Ricci tensor
- Traceless Ricci tensor
- Ricci scalar
- Einstein tensor
- Weyl tensor
- Some of the identities (e.g Bianchi) and properties

Comment: thanks for you answer. I did most of those but I'll definitly try the others